# How to get the current library name from session object

Tags: botframework

I would like to get the current library name from Session object in any dialog waterfall step.
Currently I am calling `session.dialogStack()` and extracting the id from the top dialog in the stack. Is there a better way?

Comment: I did not understand the down-vote?

Comment: You are right to use `session.dialogStack()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in your question and as Gary Liu commented, the right way to get the current dialog's Library ID is by using [`session.dialogStack()`](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/core/src/Session.ts#L560). For a UniversalBot without a `name` argument, the value defaults to `"*"`.

[UniversalBot reference](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.universalbot.html#constructor)

#### Example:

```
bot.dialog('greeting', [
  (session, args) => {
      let currentStack = session.dialogStack()
      // [ { id: '*:greeting', state: { 'BotBuilder.Data.WaterfallStep': 0 } } ]

      console.log(currentStack[currentStack.length - 1])
      // { id: '*:greeting', state: { 'BotBuilder.Data.WaterfallStep': 0 } }

      console.log(currentStack[currentStack.length - 1].id)
      // '*:greeting'

      // Separate the library name from the dialogId by calling 
      // String.prototype.split() on the stack.id. The splitter we'll use is ":".
      console.log(currentStack[currentStack.length - 1].id.split(':'))
      // [ '*', 'greeting' ]

      session.endDialog('Bye from "greeting"!')
  }
]).triggerAction({matches: /hi/ig})
```